# Android Studio: Cannot change layout button properties

Tags: android, android-layout

Created a button in Android Studio(most recent version). Trying to change the properties of the button but no changes are ever saved. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found that you should goto The Text Mode and change some things there. Would be nice if Design Mode can edit as well though.

Comment: @jason, this is the asker describing how they **actually resolved** their problem - hard to argue that isn't an answer!